# Есть ли здесь однородные обстоятельства?

Tags: пунктуация

Есть ли здесь однородные обстоятельства или все члены предложения отвечают на разные вопросы и, соответственно, запятые не нужны?

Она функционирует автоматически, без присутствия обслуживающего персонала, и может быть выполнена с использованием одной или двух накопительных емкостей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Она функционирует автоматически, без присутствия обслуживающего
>   персонала, и может быть выполнена с использованием одной или двух
>   накопительных емкостей.

Запятые проставлены верно.

См. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119 :

> **§ 23..**. Слова, поясняющие смысл предшествующего члена предложения, выделяются (или отделяются) знаками препинания (запятыми, тире,
>   двоеточием)...
>
> Перед пояснительным членом предложения обычно стоят слова ***именно, а
>   именно, то есть*** (при отсутствии в предложении эти слова могут быть
>   вставлены)...